# Integration involving vectors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

Trying to integrate the following expression (where $\bf p$, ${\bf p3}$, ${\bf q3}$, ${\bf q}$ are vectors)

$\int dq3 \int dp3 \int dq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu ^2+{\bf q3}^2} \sqrt{\mu ^2+({\bf p}-{\bf p3}-{\bf q3})^2} \sqrt{\mu ^2+(-{\bf p3}+{\bf q}-{\bf q3})^2} \left(\sqrt{\mu ^2+(-{\bf p3}+{\bf q}-{\bf q3})^2}+\sqrt{\mu ^2+{\bf q3}^2}\right)}$

Used the following:

```
q3v = Table[Subscript[q3, i], {i, 3}]; 
p3v = Table[Subscript[p3, i], {i, 3}];
qv = Table[Subscript[q, i], {i, 3}]; 
pv = Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 3}];
```

and then

```
a := 1/Sqrt[q3v^2 + \[Mu]^2]; 
b := 1/(Sqrt[q3v^2 + \[Mu]^2] + Sqrt[(-p3v + qv - q3v)^2 + \[Mu]^2]); 
c := 1/(Sqrt[(pv - p3v - q3v)^2 + \[Mu]^2]*Sqrt[(-p3v + qv - q3v)^2 + \[Mu]^2])
```

then a.b.c yields

```
{
 1/(Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (Subscript[p, 1] - Subscript[p3, 1] - Subscript[q3, 1])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 1] + Subscript[q, 1] - Subscript[q3, 1])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 1]^2]*
  (Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 1] + Subscript[q, 1] - Subscript[q3, 1])^2] + Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 1]^2])), 
 1/(Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (Subscript[p, 2] - Subscript[p3, 2] - Subscript[q3, 2])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 2] + Subscript[q, 2] - Subscript[q3, 2])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 2]^2]*
  (Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 2] + Subscript[q, 2] - Subscript[q3, 2])^2] + Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 2]^2])), 
 1/(Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (Subscript[p, 3] - Subscript[p3, 3] - Subscript[q3, 3])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 3] + Subscript[q, 3] - Subscript[q3, 3])^2]*Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 3]^2]*
  (Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + (-Subscript[p3, 3] + Subscript[q, 3] - Subscript[q3, 3])^2] + Sqrt[\[Mu]^2 + Subscript[q3, 3]^2]))
}
```

Now there are the three groups of integrals to be evaluated. Is this approach correct?

NIntegrate on the first expression, between limits -1,1, doesn't evaluate.

Thanks

Comment: The way I read your latex expression, I would expect where you have squares of vectors in your $\{a,b,c\}$ you really want dots.  i.e. `a:=1/Sqrt[ Dot[q3v,q3v] + \[Mu]^2]` etc.  That way $a$, $b$, and $c$ are scalars. Then your integrand should be `a * b * c` (product between scalars).  Still for numeric integration `NIntegrate` to work you'll need to plug in numbers for your unintegrated parameters.

Comment: The angle between each pair of vectors needs to be taken care of, hence my attempt to define the 3 components of each vector.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1172554